# Is playoff a Shakespearean term?

Tags: word-usage, etymology

The OED and other sources suggest that playoff is a construction from the late 19th century, while the [following source](https://deronbelt.wordpress.com/2015/08/15/the-playoffs-or-a-brief-etymology-lesson/) suggests that it was originally used by Shakespeare in  Henry IV.

> What does that have to do with the word playoff, then? and most importantly Shakespeare? Well, ***the word playoff comes from Shakespeare himself,***  and, even more relevant to our league—it was used colloquially in terms of drinking. ***The expression to play it off or to play off, used in Henry IV, meant “to finish what you started,” specifically to drain or finish an alcoholic drink.***

and the following extract from [Word Detective](http://www.word-detective.com/2012/02/dance-off-sing-off-etc/) appears to support such usage:

> ***This “play-off” invoked a very old sense of “off” meaning “exhaust or finish completely” (as in our modern “finish off”)***. It wasn’t until 1932 that “play-off” came to mean (first in the US, of course) “a series of games, matches, or contests played to decide a championship, competition, etc.” (Oxford English Dictionary).

The points here are the “old sense of off meaning finished” and this long periond of time (from Shakespeare’s till the 19th century) during which the above usage apparently disappeared to reemerge later  in expressions like play-off.

Questions

Was “playoff” really coined by Shakespeare with the meaning of “finish something”?

Are there other usage instances or phrasal verbs of “off” meaning finished before play-off reappeared in the 19 century?

Comment: I checked Alexander Schmidt's exhaustive [_Lexicon zu Shakespeares Werken_](https://books.google.com/books?id=Vh9XAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA72&dq=%22baffle+originally+a+punishment%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_t8Tgm6XMAhUQxmMKHfVTCK8Q6AEITTAI#v=snippet&q=%22play%2C%20subst.%201%20any%20exercise%22&f=false) (1874) and did not find any matches for "playoff," "play-off," or "play off"; the closest it has to a match is "and bids you play it off" from _Henry the Fourth_, where "play it off" means "toss it off," according to Schmidt. This is not especially closely related to a post-season elimination tournament.

Comment: Here is the excerpt from [_Henry IV Part 1_](https://books.google.com/books?id=kJ0NAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA131&dq=%22hem+and+bid+you+play+it+off%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizlJrigI_cAhUNGzQIHWmNBNYQ6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=%22hem%20and%20bid%20you%20play%20it%20off%22&f=false): "_P. Hen._ ... They call drinking deep, dying scarlet ; and when you breathe in your watering, they cry "Hem!" and bid you **play it off**. —To conclude, I am so good a proficient in one quarter of an hour, that I can drink with any tinker in his own language during my life." Precedent for the noun _playoff_? I don't think so.

Comment: [*When you drink deeply, they joke that you have been dyed red; and if you stop for a breath when you’re drinking, they yell “Cough!” and they command you to keep going. In fifteen minutes, I got so good at being a drinking companion, I could be at ease with any man over a drink, in any setting.*](http://nfs.sparknotes.com/henry4pt1/page_83.html)  "play it off" in HenryIV seems to refer to a drinking challenge or competition.

Comment: [play sb/sth off against sb/sth](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/play-sb-sth-off-against-sb-sth) *to encourage one person or group to compete or argue with another, hoping to gain some advantage from this situation:*

Comment: Why do you doubt the very sources you post, please? I'm sorry I haven't seen *Henry IV*  and how much might that matter, please?

Reading it now at Shakespeare.mit.edu/1henryiv/full.html does clearly suggest Shakespeare's "play it off" has exactly the same root as modern "play(-)off", the major difference being that "play it off" is a verbal phrase and  "play(-)off" is a noun

Answer (score 4):

Shakespeare doesn't get credit for coining "play off" because his quasi-use of the term doesn't appear to have influenced the sense as it is used today.

The *OED* does address this exact quotation in defining a compound definition of "play off."

> **1.** *trans. colloq.* To drain or finish (a drink, esp. an alcoholic one). ***Obsolete.***

Example citations:

> **1598**   Shakespeare *Henry IV*, Pt. 1 ii. v. 16   When you breath in your
> watering they cry hem, and bid you **play it off** .
>
> **1607**   T. Dekker & G. Wilkins *Iests to make you Merie sig.* H3v   He
> requested them to **play off** the sacke and begon.
>
> **1645**   H. Bold *Adventure in Poems* (1664) 136   **Play off** your Canns
> (you Rogues) your Case I'le warrant, If Fidle's good.

This might have been an existing slang sense of "play off" at the time, or it might have been an original Shakespeare coinage picked up by other period writers.  But the large gap in usage between this sense "to finish off" and the sense not attested until centuries later makes it unlikely that those who used "play-off" to mean a series of games or competitions were necessarily aware or focused on the earlier usage.

Lexicographers are interested in direct connections, and in the case of the modern term "play-off" as a noun, the origin appears to be "play off" as a verb.

> **1901**   *Munsey's Mag.* Jan. 570/1   We're going to **play off** for the Wolcott cup.

And the earlier sense meaning specifically to break a tie:

> **10.** *Sport.* **a.** *trans.* To decide the result of (a tied match) by further play.

First referred to in golf:

> **1870**   C. MacArthur *Golfer's Ann.* 118   On the tie being **played off**, Sir Robert and Mr. Anderson again tied.

Remember that "play" and "off" are common words, and their compounding can occur naturally.  This is evidenced by the number of alternate senses that exist in the interem between Shakespeare and the modern sense:

> †**3.** *trans.* To cause (a person) to be shown at a disadvantage; to make a fool of. *Obsolete.*
>
> †**4.** *trans.* To discharge, set off (artillery, a mine, a firework, etc.). Also intr.: to be discharged or fired, to go off. Also *fig. Obsolete.*
>
> **6.** *trans.* To pass off as something else.
>
> **7.** *intr. U.S.* To shirk responsibility, esp. to evade work by feigning illness. Frequently in to **play off sick**.

Answer (score 1):

Welp, the dictionary websites all say its first recorded usage was somewhere from 1890-1895, but aren't helpful enough to explain *where* or *by whom*. Still, while Shakespeare might be responsible for "play off", he doesn't appear to get the credit for playoff.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/playoff
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/playoff